# How to add compile options to an external library in C++?

Tags: c++, cmake

### Overview

**Context**

- I'm using Clion, and I try to use the C++ google's benchmark library in my project.

**My problem**

- My project has a build type `Debug`, when I compile it, the benchmark library is also compiled as `Debug`. **BUT** I need the library to be build as `Release` for it to work properly.

**The (not good enough) solution**

- I have to add '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release' to [Clion's Cmake options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIZtE.png), however it's now the whole project witch is in `Release`

#### How do I impose to one library to compile with different options ?

**My code (cmake)**

```
#My target (I wnat it to run in debug)
add_executable(benchmark_test
        thread/benchmark_test.cpp
        thread/benchmark_test.h)

# prevent lib to run tests
set(BENCHMARK_ENABLE_TESTING NO)

# Importing the lib (source code at the root of the project)
# I want it to run in release
add_subdirectory(benchmark)

# Linking the target and the lib
target_link_libraries(benchmark_test benchmark)
```

**What didn't work so far**

```
# I would have thought this one to put everything in release but no (maybe because of Clion)
add_compile_options(-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release)

#===================================================================

# This was my most advanced try so far 
set(GCC_COMPILE_OPTIONS "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release")
target_compile_options(benchmark_main PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${GCC_COMPILE_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>")
target_compile_options(benchmark PUBLIC "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:${GCC_COMPILE_DEBUG_OPTIONS}>")
```

I'm kinda new here, just tell me if there is any lack of information ^^

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, since release/debug is a project-wide setting.  Your easiest option is probably to build the benchmark library separately, then use those artifacts when building your main project.

Comment: Not sure if FetchContent allows thism, but certainly you could build&install the release configuration of for benchmark lib and use `find_package` to import the package. (I assume the benchmark lib does provide a package configuration script)

Comment: Have you considered building everything in `RelWithDebInfo`? Google Benchmark should still work in that mode and you still get debugging symbols in your program. It's not possible in general to mix `Debug` and `Release`. On Windows, without special configuration, this will result in symbol errors from two separate C runtimes being linked together.

Comment: Hey @StephenNewell ! I was trying to do your solution before answering, but it seems I struggle also to import the library once it's built  ;_; ... 

Could you also tell me how you would do that ?  
My code looks like this, it compiles, but when I include the lib in my code it's not detection the lib : 
```cmake
set(LIB_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/benchmark/build/src/libbenchmark.a)
add_library(benchmark SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET benchmark_test benchmark PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION "${LIB_LOCATION}")

target_link_libraries(benchmark_test benchmark)
```

Comment: Use `find_package` or `find_library`.  Plenty of examples online, but if you can't figure it out then [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: If you do a separate build/install for the benchmark library, the [`MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG` target property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MAP_IMPORTED_CONFIG_CONFIG.html) may be useful (or maybe not. just an fyi).